# Log Service Stub Testbed Python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, testbed

```
class MyTestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        from google.appengine.ext import testbed
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()

        self.testbed.init_mail_stub()
        self.mail_stub = self.testbed.get_stub(testbed.MAIL_SERVICE_NAME)

        self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()
        self.taskqueue_stub = self.testbed.get_stub(
            testbed.TASKQUEUE_SERVICE_NAME)

        self.testbed.init_logservice_stub()
        self.log_stub = self.testbed.get_stub(testbed.LOG_SERVICE_NAME)

    def testMailSent(self):
        mail.send_mail(to='alice@example.com',
                       subject='This is a test',
                       sender='bob@example.com',
                       body='This is a test e-mail')
        messages = self.mail_stub.get_sent_messages(to='alice@example.com')
        self.assertEqual(1, len(messages))
        self.assertEqual('alice@example.com', messages[0].to)

    def testTaskAddedToQueue(self):
        taskqueue.Task(name='my_task', url='/url/of/my/task/').add()
        tasks = self.taskqueue_stub.get_filtered_tasks()
        self.assertEqual(len(tasks), 1)
        self.assertEqual(tasks[0].name, 'my_task')

    def testLogAddedtoLogs(self):
        logging.info('hi')
        logs = self.log_stub. #WHAT METHOD TO CALL HERE
        self.assertEqual(len(logs), 1)
```

No documentation given here on how to use logservice_stub
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/localunittesting
Someone please help.

Comment: What is the issue, so what is your actual question?

Comment: see `def testLogAddedtoLogs`. Dont know which method to use to get the logs.

Comment: Like we have: 
`messages = self.mail_stub.get_sent_messages(to='alice@example.com')`
`tasks = self.taskqueue_stub.get_filtered_tasks()`

What do I use to get the logs?

Comment: @Capricorn do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to browse the source and figure it out unfortunately

`from google.appengine.ext import testbed` is here:

[https://github.com/optimizely/python-appengine/blob/master/google/appengine/ext/testbed/**init**.py](https://github.com/optimizely/python-appengine/blob/master/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py)

But I think this is ultimately the file you want:

https://github.com/optimizely/python-appengine/blob/master/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py

Comment: In the second documentation, pay attention to the start_request and end_request functions, those should contain the information you need.

Comment: greatt. I was able to figure out the first documentation, but couldn't find the second. Thankyou for the help!